# How to use ubsan for llvm .bc file

Tags: llvm, sanitize, ubsan

Suppose I have a file called put.bc. It doesn't have strings "asan_report" and "ubsan_handles" in it.
If I use command `clang -fsanitize=address -emit-llvm -o put-asan.bc -c put.bc` directly, "asan_report" will not appear in put-asan.bc.
So,I write a pass1.cpp:

```
for (Function &F : M)
    {
        F.addFnAttr(Attribute::SanitizeAddress);
    }
```

compile it to pass1.so.
I use command `clang -Xclang -load -Xclang pass1.so -emit-llvm -o put-tem.bc -c put.bc`.
And the comand `clang -fsanitize=address -emit-llvm -o put-asan.bc -c put-tem.bc`.
So, put-asan.bc has strings "asan_report" or something else. This means that asan instrumentation was successfully used on it. I don't know how to use ubsan to instrument put.bc. Because there's no `F.addFnAttr(Attribute::SanitizeUndefined);` like asan.

Is there a way to get the put-ubsan.bc from put.bc? What should I do?

Im using llvm 12.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ASan TSan and MSan which are LLVM passes that can run over any LLVM IR, UBSan is a feature of clang which changes the LLVM IR that is produced from the original C++ source code. This is an essential part of how UBSan works as UBSan detects things that are undefined behaviour in terms of the C++ language standard, even when the equivalent LLVM IR has well defined behaviour.